# equivalent full hours of heating equipment

Tags: heat-transfer, heating-systems, building-physics

I would like to know if there is a standard way of calculating the equivalent to a *capacity factor* but for heating equipment. That is the ratio between the amount of heat delivered during one year divided by the amount of heat that could be delivered by the equipment (capacity x time in a year). Or otherwise, the equivalent full load heating hours divided by the number of hours of the year.

I thought of an approximation, dividing the average annual heating degree days by the maximum annual heating degree days of the city where the building is situated.  I would like to compare it with other ways of estimating the same factor.

Comment: What is the end goal that you are trying to determine?  I am curious about a similar concept so I was waiting to comment hoping you would get some other answers, but nothing so far.  One of the problems you may encounter is that you probably need to define your heating degree days.  It is technically the number of hours that the ambient temperature is below a specified temperature and given in the number of days worth of hours.  To that end, ASHRAE data for any city specifies it for both 50 degrees and 65 degrees, so you need to be sure what you're looking for.

Comment: It's part of a bigger techno-economic model. I just want to have an estimation of how much the equipment is actually used (is one of the important economic factors to decide which equipment would be more economic to install). I think I am going to go for a comparison using the bin method to calculate the "equivalent full load heating hours". I have hourly temperature data for several years for the city I am studying, so calculating HDD is not a problem.